# Objectify Web Safe Key Usage

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using `Objectify` to store and retrieve data from App Engine Datastore.

String version of the key is created from the datastore object id.

```
public String getWebsafeKey() {
    return Key.create(UserData.class, id).getString();
}
```

The `websafeKey` is used to get the UserData object from the Datastore.

```
Key<UserData> userDataKey = Key.create(websafeKey);
UserData userData = ofy().load().key(userDataKey).now();
```

In our Unit testing when the `websafeKey` is changed a bit, the user data class can still be retrieved.

Passed websafeKey - `agxqfmMyaHF1YWxpdHlyEgsSBU1vdmllGICAgJDSioELDC`

Actual websafeKey - `agxqfmMyaHF1YWxpdHlyEgsSBU1vdmllGICAgJDSioELDA`

Is this a known limitation or this can be addressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`websafeKey`'s are base64 encoded strings.

Somehow both

`agxqfmMyaHF1YWxpdHlyEgsSBU1vdmllGICAgJDSioELDC` &
`agxqfmMyaHF1YWxpdHlyEgsSBU1vdmllGICAgJDSioELDA` decode to `jj~c2hqualityrMovie`

give it a try https://www.base64decode.org/